# Can you invert integral sign for an arbitrary function?

Tags: integration

I have this identity. Here, $F(x)$ is the data distribution I have while $f(x)$ is the function I want to find.

$$F(x)=\int f(\sqrt{x^2+t^2})dt $$

Question: can you express $f(x)$ in the general case? I was able to find solutions for several well-defined functions.
For example, if $f(x)$ is normal distribution, solution is $f(x)=-{\sigma\over(\sqrt{\pi}x)}\cdot{dF(x)\over dx}$, but solution for arbitrary functions eludes me despite looking like a very simple case.

I understand that some functions will be non-convergent, so integrals can be definite from 0 to some finite number, if it helps calculation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $F(x) = \int f(t)dt \implies f(x) = \frac{d F(x)}{dx}$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I think you want it to be a definite instead of indefinite integral. It looks like $F(x)$ is also a function of $t$, is that what you want?

Comment: You can reduce it to a more complicated equation by applying the derivative to both sides - $F'(x) = 2x\int f'(\sqrt{x^2+t^2})dt + f(\sqrt{2x^2})$. I don't believe there is a full generalisation. EDIT: $f'$ meaning derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: @LeeFisher Solution for definite version will be appreciated. But since I found a few solutions for indefinite, I hope that there is a generalized solution for indefinite one.

Comment: @Kolja I'm not sure how to simplify this form. Can you elaborate?